# Sending a list within an object to Wcf Service

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, wcf, jquery

I use `Wcf Service` and `JS`.

I send information to my service by `AJAX`.

I have a function in the service that accepts the following object:

```
  [DataContract]
    public class Business
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Desc { get; set; }        
        [DataMember]
        public List<BusinessService> Services { get; set; }
    }
```

the BusinessService.cs:

```
   [DataContract]
    public class BusinessService
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int LongTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I parse the objects in my JS to `JSON` and send them to the service.

**Here the json that send to the wcf function:**

```
"{"ManageBusiness":{"Name":"aaaaaa","Desc":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","Services":[{"Name":"aaaaaa","Desc":"aaaaaa","LongTime":30},{"Name":"aaaaaa1","Desc":"aaaaaa","LongTime":30}]}}"
```

Everything works as it should except the `Services` list.

The list comes to the wcf function as null.

I have no idea why this is happening, I would appreciate help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a `List<T>` from JSON data. What you can do, is replace :

```
[DataContract]
    public class Business
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Desc { get; set; }        
        [DataMember]
        public List<BusinessService> Services { get; set; }
    }
```

with

```
[DataContract]
    public class Business
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Desc { get; set; }        
        [DataMember]
        public BusinessService[] Services { get; set; }
    }
```

That is, replace `List<T>` with `Array of T`

Comment: It also did not help. The list continues to get null.

Comment: Well, your JSON representation is well formed so I cannot understand what can be wrong, can you send some more code? For example the c# code that handles the call and the javascript code that sends the request?

Comment: Is it really working? I am also going through same scenario! I need that code.

Comment: Yes you can a List<T> from JSON data.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WCF Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to help you view and trace the errors you get from the service.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var data = "{"ManageBusiness":{"Name":"aaaaaa","Desc":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","Services":[{"Name":"aaaaaa","Desc":"aaaaaa","LongTime":30},{"Name":"aaaaaa1","Desc":"aaaaaa","LongTime":30}]}}";
```

Add below in the ajax call

```
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify({ business: data }),
```

the below code to receive the data

```
public ActionResult BusinessCall(Business business){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following I can say definitively works.  I just tested it. Sorry its in vb.net, but you should get the idea.

On the server side:
In IService1.vb

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

Namespace Webservices
   <ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)> _
    Function test(manageBusiness As ManagedBusiness) As string

   End Interface
End Namespace
```

In Service1.svc.vb

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Namespace Webservices
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)>
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1 
    Public function test(manageBusiness As ManagedBusiness) As string Implements IService1.test 
       Return "done"   
     End function    
End Class   

<CollectionDataContract()>
Public Class Services
    Inherits List(Of Service)
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class Service
    <DataMember()>Public Property Name As String
    <DataMember()>Public Property Desc As String
    <DataMember()>Public Property LongTime As Integer 
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class ManagedBusiness 
    <DataMember()>Public Property Name As String
    <DataMember()>Public Property Desc As String
    <DataMember()>Public Property Services As Services

End Class 
End NameSpace
```

I wired up the webconfig settings.  And put this jquery ajax call on the client side:

```
$("#btnTest").click(function () {
            var services = [];
            services.push({
                Name: "aaaaaa",
                Desc: "aaaaaa",
                LongTime: 30
            });
            services.push({
                Name: "aaaaaa1",
                Desc: "aaaaaa",
                LongTime: 30
            });
            var data = {};
            data.manageBusiness = {
                Name: "aaaaaa",
                Desc: "aaaaaaaaaaaa",
                Services: services
            }


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:64110/Webservices/Service1.svc/test",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success(msg) {

                }
            });


        });
```

I can confirm that the Requested Payload was as follows:

```
{"manageBusiness":{"Name":"aaaaaa","Desc":"aaaaaaaaaaaa","Services":[{"Name":"aaaaaa","Desc":"aaaaaa","LongTime":30},{"Name":"aaaaaa1","Desc":"aaaaaa","LongTime":30}]}}
```

And the WCF service deserialized everything just fine.  I think what you were missing was the  **[CollectionDataContract]** attribute.

UPDATE: I tried removing the [CollectionDataContract] attribute and it STILL worked.  So I am guessing that the data contract attributes are only for serializing, not needed for deserializing (?)